# Create 2 Filters for one collection (Shopify)

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create 2 drop-down lists to filter one collection of products
I looked all over the internet and I couldn't find a tutorial for that.

I know what I need to do but I don't know how. So if you can, please, answer any of the following questions so I can move on with my code:

1. How can I create a drop-down list of all tags built in this structure: “PRODUCT_Socks”
2. How can I get the value selected in a drop-down list () and use it afterwards?
3. How can I hide the beginning of the tag? - hide the “PRODUCT_” so customers will only see “Socks”.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link, Hope this will be helpful

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/collections/filter-collections-with-product-tags

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/collections/filtering-a-collection-with-multiple-tag-drop-down

Comment: With some work on the second one, It works great! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

basically whatever is being used to output the tags ...i.e.{{ product.tags | remove: 'PRODUCT_'}} that should get you the tag you want